# Visual studio 2015 renders some characters as squares (tofus)

Tags: windows-10, fonts, visual-studio-2015, rendering

I've got a recent problem with visual studio after updating windows 10 to the anniversary update.

[image: Image of the bug]

Weirdly, it happens on the same characters, but not anytime, sometimes it doesn't; sometimes not.

Comment: repair/reinstall visual studio. If that doesn't do it, it sounds like your OS was damaged.  in that case try the System File Checker: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833

Comment: Mmm... I'll try that, also : I installed the UWP toolkit from visual studio just after updating to the AU. Maybe that. It only happens in vs

Comment: @FrankThomas  I repaired Visual studio, but this bug still happens. Now it happens specifically on "symbol" expected, it replaces with "(square)" expected